# (electron) how to attach a browser window to desktop

Tags: javascript, electron

Is it possible to attach a window to desktop, I have seen some literature on it in Google but it wasn't too sure. I know you can on Mac but not sure on Linux/windows.

I am building a custom desktop application if you want to know the use case.

Comment: What does "attach a window to desktop" mean?

Comment: I mean when you use the shortcut to desktop (hid running apps) it still use my program. I am making a launcher.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? Thanks!